# Index of a Listview

Tags: jquery, html, jquery-mobile, jquery-plugins

Appending is correct and its populating listview. What i want is to get the index of every listview populated when its was click. But its always 0 index in my alert message. How to get the index of every listview? thanks

Html code

```
<ul id="RecipeList" data-role="listview" data-split-icon="star" data-split-theme="a" data-inset="true "href="#recpdetail">                 
</ul>
```

JS Code

```
for(var i=0; i<NameArr.length; i++){
    var $content = $('<li><a href="#recpdetail"><img src="../../img/album-bb.jpg"><h3>Name: '+ NameArr[i] + '</h3><p>Code: '+ CodeArr[i]+ '</p><p>Category: '+ CatArr[i]+ '</p></a><a href="#purchase" data-rel="popup" data-position-to="window" data-transition="pop">Add to favorites</a></li>');                              
    $('#RecipeList').append($content).listview('refresh');
}
```

Codes for index

```
$("#RecipeList").click(function(){
    var selected_index = $(this).find('li').index();
    alert('Selected Index = ' + selected_index);
});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here the problem is you are always getting the index of the first `li` element instead of the clicked `li`.

Change your click event to target the `li` elements inside `RecipeList` as below

```
$("#RecipeList").on('click', 'li', function(){
    var selected_index = $(this).index();
    alert('Selected Index = ' + selected_index);
});
```